# Using sed or tr to capitalize the last letter of words that begin with a specified character/expression

Tags: regex, sed, tr

I want to capitalize the last letter of words that begin with certain letters.

Example: `At The Movies` to `AT ThE Movies`

I tried...

```
$ sed 's/\<[ABEXY][[:alpha:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\>\)/\U\1/g' file1
```

But this replaces all the words I am trying to change with an upper case of their last letter

Also tried:

```
$ sed '/\<[ABEXY][[:alpha:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\>\)/ y/\1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/\1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/' file1
```

But backcalling doesn't work with `sed y` So I just got all caps.

Comment: `tr` is not the command to use; it unconditionally maps all occurrences of the characters it is told to map.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the start of the word too, and include it in the replacement:

```
sed 's/\<\([ABEXY][[:alpha:]]*\)\([[:alpha:]]\>\)/\1\U\2/g' file1
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel very silly now to have missed something so simple.